# How do I recover from a "error: unknown file system grub" boot error?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

I have dual boot system with Windows 7 and 10.04. Recently I have installed 12.04 over 10.04. Now when I start my computer it shows following message:

```
error: unknown file system 
grub rescue
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix that is with super grub disk. This is a disk that will automatically will fix grub for you. [Get it Here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

To know more about Grub [Please Read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Get a live disk (any distro), boot into it and enter the following commands from the terminal -

**sudo grub-install /dev/sda**

**sudo update-grub**