# How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>

Tags: grub2

I get this error:

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

I'm not exactly sure what I did. I believe I installed Ubuntu over Windows on my Acer netbook. I then tried to install [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint), but it wouldn't start installing.

I turned the netbook off and back on. Now I get the error.

I have read a lot of other questions like this, but in my case I cannot boot a CD. If I put a Ubuntu CD or a Linux Mint CD into my external CD/DVD drive and change my BIOS to boot the CD-ROM first, it just gives me the same error screen.

**Update copied from comment dated 2012-05-26 02:54:29Z**

Here are some results from my commands:

```
grub rescue>ls (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) 
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos5) unknown filesystem 
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos1) unknown filesystem 
grub rescue>ls (hd0) unknown filesystem
```

Comment: do you have ubuntu live ISO in internal hard drive?

Comment: If there is no defect in either your Ubuntu or Mint install CDs then either your hardware is broken or your BIOS is simply not trying to boot from the CD even though you think you told it to do that. Please take a look at the troubleshooting suggestions listed on the [**BootFromCD**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) help page.

Comment: I did what [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/179662/22949) said to do, but instead of (hd0,1) I put (hd0,3). I suggest trying that command with 1-6 instead of just 1 or 0. But try 0 too.

Comment: The answers below DO NOT WORK!  This DOES WORK: re-install ubuntu.  Select "do something else".  When prompted, select your Windows partition as the boot partition.  Do not select /boot or / as the boot partition.  If you have an existing Windows installation, Ubuntu will come to this state.  This is tested working and common knowledge.  Persists: 14, 15, 16, 17 all versions.  You might be unable to boot to Windows without the Ubuntu drive in your computer after doing this (untested).  Possibly happens because your computer is selecting the wrong boot device (untested).

Answer (score 89):

The following solved the issue for me, I have Windows 7 & Ubuntu 10.04. After running the following commands I don't need to run these every time and am able to boot both the OS normally:

```
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Now once you boot into Ubuntu, run the following two commands as well:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Note: `/dev/sda` is drive where you want your GRUB installed, it can be `/dev/sdb` or something else, but is usually `/dev/sda`

Take into consideration that the `hd0` could be X (0,1,2..) depending on the order of disks and the `6` could be also different, it could be `(hd0,gpt7)`, for example.

Comment: I have a MacBook Air with Ubuntu and OSX, this solved my issues after the OSX Mavericks update!

Comment: Thanks a lot. ( @Hjke123 this should be the accepted answer ! While the first post gives hints on how to get the Ubuntu disk/partition  IDs ...)

Comment: Excellent. These steps solved by issue. Just make sure that `/dev/sda` is your harddisk, which is the case most of the time.

Comment: As I have /boot on other partition, it was
`set root=(hd0,gpt7)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/grub`
for me, but it worked, thank you very much.

Comment: insmod normal returns `error: unknown filesystem.`.

Comment: no such partition

Comment: For me it was `(hd0,msdos1)`. I also had to `set root=(hd0,msdos1)/@` instead of `set root=(hd0,msdos1)`, and I also had to do this: `set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/@/boot/grub`. Only then the rest of the commands worked.

Comment: I figured I needed to enter the `@` because when I did `ls (hd0,msdos1)`, what I got was these two directories: `@/ @home/`. I don't know why this was the case for me, maybe someone with more knowledge can give an explanation, but for what it's worth, try doing this if you can't get `insmod normal` to work, that's how I got it to work on my machine.

Comment: Use `(hdX,gptY)`, when you have a GPT-partitiontable and use `(hdX, msdosY)`, when you have a MBR-partitiontable. You can also just try `(hdX,Y)`. X = "disk-number" - 1 and Y = partition-number. So the disks starts at 0 and the partitions start at 1. To see all disks and partitions enter `ls`.

Comment: The cause of my errors was adding a new parition. Using `set` to find the current values, and using `set` to add 1 to the msdos, it fixed it.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone This is most likely because you use btrfs, and they default to having two volumes in most installation, "@" for root filesystem, and "@home" for your home directories, being mounted respectively at / and /home by your system when you boot. However, on the raw mounted partition they are presented as you've seen when you mount it...

Answer (score 39):

**First boot into Ubuntu from an ISO image.**

1. Locate the Ubuntu partition and the folder containing the GRUB modules.

   The GRUB folder containing the modules must be located so the correct modules can be loaded. This folder would have been created during the initial installation of Ubuntu and should be located in the Ubuntu partition. This folder would normally be located at either *(hdX,Y)/boot/grub or (hdX,Y)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc*. Find your existing Ubuntu partition and the module folder.

   ```
   ls                               # List the known drives (hdX) and partitions (hdX,Y)
   ls (hdX,Y)/                      # List the contents of the partition's root
   ls (hdX,Y)/boot/grub             # Normal location of the Grub 2 modules.
   ls (hdX,Y)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc  # Alternate location of the Grub 2 modules.
   ```

   - `ls` - should return all known drives (hdX) and partitions (hdX,Y)
   - `ls (hdX,Y)/` - should show the contents of the root directory of the
     partition.
   - If you get an *"error: unknown filesystem"* this is not your Ubuntu
     partition.
   - If this is the Ubuntu partition, you will see the Ubuntu
     folders, including lost+found/, home/, boot/ and vmlinuz and
     initrd.img. Use this address as the first part of the next
     command.
   - `ls (hdX,Y)/boot/grub` - should display several dozen *.mod files. This is the folder you are looking for.
   - If you don't find the modules, try the alternate location: ls (hdX,Y)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc
2. Load the modules.

   ```
   set prefix=(hdX,Y)/<path to modules>
   ```

   - This command must correctly point to the folder containing the GRUB modules. The address should be the one in the previous section which displayed the modules.

   Examples:

   ```
   set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub 
   set prefix=(hd1,1)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc
   ```

   - Load modules:

     ```
     insmod linux
     insmod loopback
     insmod iso9660
     insmod fat        # If ISO is located on fat16 or fat32 formatted partition.
     insmod ntfs       # If ISO is located on an NTFS formatted partition.
     insmod nftscomp   # If NTFS compression is used on the partition. Load if you aren't sure.
     ```
   - A *"file not found"* error means that the path in the prefix is incorrect or the specific module does not exist. The prefix setting may be reviewed with the set command. Rerun the "set prefix=" command with the proper path.
3. Locate the Ubuntu ISO file.

   - Using the combinations of ls commands, locate the Ubuntu ISO image.
4. Create the loopback device.

   ```
   loopback loop (hdX,Y)/<path to ISO>/<ISO-name.iso>
   ```

   - Example:

     ```
     loopback loop (hd1,1)/path/to/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
     ```
5. Load the Linux kernel and initrd image.

   ```
   set root=(loop)
   linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/<ISO-name.iso> noprompt noeject
   initrd /casper/initrd.lz
   ```

   - *If the path to the ISO or filename is not correct, the boot will halt at the BusyBox screen and produce a message stating "can't open
     /dev/sr0: No medium found".*
   - Note: If the ISO file is not in the / folder, include the path in the
     `iso-scan/filename= entry`. See second example.
   - Examples:

     ```
     linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
     linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/my-iso/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
     ```
6. Boot.

   That should be it. If the commands ran without any messages/errors,
   the commands were accepted as entered. It's now time to boot:

   ```
   boot
   ```

Further information is in forum post *[HOWTO: Boot & Install Ubuntu from the Grub Rescue Prompt](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293)*

**Now do this after booting:**

*[How to fix: error:unknown file system grub rescue?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930610)* is post with the same problem and is solved as below,

1. `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

   Here, `sdaX` is your boot partition. You can get a list with `sudo blkid` like this,

   ```
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows XP" UUID="96A4390DA438F0FB" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda3: LABEL="Ubuntu 11.04" UUID="b61fcae3-7744-45b4-95b9-7528d50a3652" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda5: LABEL="Se7en" UUID="A2DC9D71DC9D4109" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda6: LABEL="Development" UUID="DEB455A1B4557CC9" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda7: LABEL="EXTRA" UUID="D8A04109A040F014" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda8: LABEL="SONG" UUID="46080FCD080FBAC7" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda9: LABEL="BACKUPS" UUID="766E-BC99" TYPE="vfat"
   ```

   Note: `sdaX` must be Linux partition.
2. `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`
3. `sudo update-grub`

Comment: when I use the sudo blkid it says "Unknow command "sudo"

Comment: As I said ^^ I can't do the sudo command.

Comment: `blkid` and all this with `sudo` is pricess to do after booting into live image.

Comment: Is there any way to repair grub without installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner You don't need to install Ubuntu - just enter the above commands after booting into the live system! (You can do this without (re)install Ubuntu).

Answer (score 15):

Boot your system from the Ubuntu Live CD and try this, it worked wonders for me.

- [Ubuntu Boot Repair Utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: It also worked for me!  I got into problem when I downsized my Windows partition to create a new  NTFS partition for my data with the released space (I did it with Partition Magic, a Windows software).  I rebooted my computer with my Ubuntu DVD and downloaded & executed boot-repair which was able to see all the partitions on my hard drive and repair Grub.

Comment: In linux mint 18.3 64 bit cinnamon, it is works...
Thanks @user91463.. you saved my life

Comment: This tool is GodSent. I was struggling with the randomness in boot due to installing CentOS in place of my Dual Boot Ubuntu. CentOS didn't allow me to log in to Windows for some reason. When I tried to bring back Ubuntu, everything messed up. It wasn't even allowing me to install Ubuntu again. This worked like charm.

Answer (score 7):

**Before reading:** The answer below is meant for Ubuntu users who have just updated/recovered/reinstalled/installed OS X. It's likely that the answer will work if this isn't the case (for example, if there are any inconsistencies in your partition table), but I'm not sure.

For me, this happened after updating to [OS X Mavericks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (10.9). Basically what may have happened is that OS X created a recovery partition ("Recovery HD") that the system only detects *sometimes*. For example, [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) in Ubuntu will see the recovery partition fine, but when listing the partitions in terminal (`fdisk -l`), you may not see the partitions.

### Diagnosing the issue: Did the OS X update/format/recovery cause this problem?

In order to diagnose that this is indeed the case, first use [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) rescue to boot into Ubuntu. In order to do this, follow [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell.html) or see if any of the other answers on this question can get you into Ubuntu. For me, running the below commands temporarily allowed me to boot the correct partition. Depending on how your hard drives and partitions are set up, it may vary:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

Now, log in to Ubuntu and check GParted. If you see the recovery partition, open up a terminal and type `fdisk -l` to see if that detects the recovery partition. If it doesn't list the same partitions, check the device/partition column and see if those also don't match up (for example, in GParted your boot partition may be `/dev/sda4`, but it is `/dev/sda3` when running `fdisk`). If this is the case, keep reading. If it's not, it looks like your partitions are lined up correctly. You can either choose to keep reading and follow the instructions (which, if GRUB was working before the restore/reinstall/etc..., this should work properly), or just reinstall GRUB on the right partition.

### Fixing it by removing/merging the recovery partition

To fix this issue, what we want to do is get rid of the recovery partition - it's causing issues and inconsistencies, and removing it shouldn't cause damage. Ideally you want to merge it with the normal [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) OS X partition, so follow this question and answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/apple-recovery-partition-possibly-creating-problems-in-ubuntu). After merging, GRUB should be back to normal.

Comment: Removing the recovery-partition of course disables your ability to use it, so I'd say this is not a good option. Better try reinstalling GRUB2 and then "updating" (this is regenerating) it's config as described in the other answers. You may also use one of the recovery tools.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after I delete a partition that was located before the `/boot` partition.

To fix it, I ran an Ubuntu live USB stick, mounted the root partition to `/mnt` and the boot partition to `/mnt/boot`, and I ran this command (replace `/dev/sda` with the correct hard disk):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Your external CD/DVD is probably a USB device.  You probably cannot tell BIOS to boot from it.  When you start the ACER wacth for a message at the bottom (or top) of the screen saying something like "F2 to enter Setup, F12 for a Boot Menu".  When you know what you need to press for the Boot Menu, put the CD in your external device, turn on or reboot the machine and slowly mash that key until you get a temporary menu allowing you to boot from the external CD.

You may need to use gparted from the CD to examine your hard drive and decide what to do to fix it so you can use it.  That's beyond what I can describe here

Comment: Here are some results from my commands :
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos5)
unknown filesystem
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos1)
unknown filesystem
grub rescue>ls (hd0)
unknown filesystem I don't know if this will mean anything to anyone trying to help and thanks for the response I will check

Comment: He should be able to select his USB-drive from the BIOS-boot-order-selection menu - at least if he is using UEFI mode.