# Recovering moved .mod files using grubrescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I did a dumb thing... I forgot that Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) switched to [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) 2 which puts a ton of *.mod files (kernel modules) in `/boot/grub`. I thought they were soundtrack files put there erroneously, and I moved them. Needless to say, the next reboot was traumatic. I was presented with something I had no memory of ever seeing... a 'grub rescue>' prompt.

With the help of [Fixing GRUB error: “error: unknown filesystem”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem) however, I was able to recover...

- I discovered that GRUB rescue does not have 'cd', 'cp' or any other filesystem commands except its own variation of 'ls'.
- So first I had to find the partition with the `/boot` directory containing `vmlinuz` file and other boot image files... *(approximation from memory of failed attempts, as well as blank lines for clarity, added 2014-07-10 by docsalvage)*

  ```
  grub rescue>  ls  
  (hd0,4) (hd0,3) (hd0,2) (hd0,1)  

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,4)/boot
  ... some kind of 'not found' message

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,3)/boot
  ... some kind of 'not found' message

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,2)/boot
  ... grub ... initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic ... vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic
  ```
- I found a `/boot` directory containing the `vmlinuz` file `vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic` on partition `(hd0,2)`.
- Then I manually booted from the 'grub rescue>' prompt. The following commands will...

  - Set the `root` to use the `/boot` directory on partition `(hd0,2)`.
  - Load kernel module `linux`.
  - Set that module to use the kernel image `vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic`.
  - Set initrd(initialize RAM disk) to use the image `initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic`.
  - Boot Linux.
- ```
  grub rescue>  set root=(hd0,2)/boot  
  grub rescue>  insmod linux  
  grub rescue>  linux (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic root=/dev/sda2
  grub rescue>  initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic  
  grub rescue>  boot
  ```
- This boots and crashes to the BusyBox prompt which DOES have some rudimentary filesystem commands.
- Then I moved the *.mod files back to the `/boot/grub` directory...

  ```
  busybox>  cd /boot  
  busybox>  mv mod/* grub
  busybox>  reboot
  ```
- The reboot was successful, but that was a lot of work.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Boot-Repair would be way easier, in my opinion. Check out one of my [multiple answers](http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a40421%20body%3a%22boot-repair%22) on Boot-Repair for details on using it.

Comment: The "easiest" way is not always the best way. I strongly disagree with all the comments that suggest using a Live CD; it's really very difficult to boot from a Live CD on systems that don't have a CD/DVD reader.

Comment: ican not locate the partition with the /boot directory.All partitions upon ls command give unknown filesystem output.

Comment: I've added some details to the "question" above that may help.

Comment: Thanks , Upon ls command I get (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) and I have tried /boot with each of them and always it says unknown file system.Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the first partition is `(hd0)` and not something like `(hd0,0)`? I assume the others are MSDOS formatted partitions. Wish I could be of more help. Can anyone else help? I'm getting into the weeds.

Comment: Your post was very helpful for manually booting the kernel and initrd, but my system could not find dev, sys or proc, etc/fstab or sbin/init. That led me to another [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120198/17109), which suggested loading the kernel and setting the root as detailed in the manual boot directions in the [grub documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GNU_002fLinux.html), _eg:_ `grub> linux (hd0,X)/boot/vmlinuz-a.b.c-d-generic root=/dev/sdaX`, where `X` is the partition with `/boot`, `a.b.c-d` is the kernel version. Then my system booted fine! Thanks!

Comment: in addition to [Fixing GRUB error: “error: unknown filesystem” [duplicate]](http://askubuntu.com/q/142300/36961) another great link that covers these steps is [How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/), the [grub 2 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GNU_002fLinux.html) is also very helpful

Comment: I have had the same ptoblem, stuck in grub_+rescue when upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, but the situation is even worse because I do not have the alt gr key, so no slash key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I think you pretty much found the easiest way to recover from the state of your system using **grub rescue**; it is a very minimalistic system giving just enough capability to boot the system.

BTW, I believe you must have found the `.mod` files and executed `insmod linux` or the `linux` command would have failed.

The only other way, as mentioned, would be to boot a Live CD and reinstall grub2 after chroot'ing to the 'broken' system.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I forgot that I'd done that. Added to my original post above for future reference.

I need to be more disciplined in keeping careful notes in these situations. Please advise if further edits are needed.

Comment: I also had to specify root when loading the kernel as in the [grub docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GNU_002fLinux.html) _eg_ `grub> linux (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic root=/dev/sda2`

Comment: Also note, if you found the .mod files, you can restore „grub rescue” to fully-featured GRUB:

`# Inspect the current prefix (and other preset variables):
set
# Find out which devices are available:
ls
# Set to the correct value, which might be something like this:
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
normal`

Source:
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell.html

Answer (score 7):

Here are some general and basic instructions to help with boot errors such as `GRUB loading stage 1.5 error 15`    (e.g. after the installation of Windows on different disk drive) :

1. Boot with a LiveDVD (e.g., the Ubuntu Desktop disk).
2. Open a terminal, and re-write the grub configuration using these commands:

   - `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
   - `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX`

Where `/dev/sdX` is the disk where Ubuntu is installed, and `/dev/sdXY` is the partition on the disk where Ubuntu is installed.  In other words, `/dev/sdXY` contains `/boot` and so on.

Use `fdisk -l` to verify the Ubuntu installation location.

Comment: Did not work.  Perhaps if the directions were more specific, it would have worked.

Comment: When I had a grub2 problem on a machine without cd drive I was able to recover by using my Gparted Live usb memory stick drive.  I booted into Gparted live. THEN I started a terminal and typed fdisk  -l  (that's letter ell, not number 1) The output from that let me identify the partition which had the root partition and from there I followed the excellent instructions above and I was soon happily dual booting again.

Answer (score 4):

1. Boot into Live CD
2. Open Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
3. Enter the following commands:

`sudo fdisk -l`

And find your Ubuntu partition (should be /dev/sda1 if it is the first partition)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now reinstall Grub2

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub2
```

Comment: Is this a better way better than `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` and `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda && sudo update-grub`?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I upgraded my system.

I suggest the following simple steps:

1. Boot your system with ubuntu live CD or live USB.
2. Open the terminal and run the command
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
3. Then install boot repair by running the command 
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
4. Launch the boot repair after installing.
   For example, from the menu, use `System->Administration->Boot-Repair`  (Ubuntu 10.04 only) and follow the instructions.

   It may take 15-20 min to figure out the problem and to fix it.

For more help go to the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You could boot live CD, mount your hard drive, open nautilus as root and copy those files to /boot.