# Ubuntu 12.04 Install on Lenovo x120e - Grub menu loads, but won't load Ubuntu without USB in

Tags: 12.04, grub2, usb, boot-repair

I've installed Ubuntu using a USB
The grub menu then would not load, so I followed:

To reinstall GRUB:

Make a new Ubuntu Live CD and Boot from it.

Install boot-repair using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

At this point, I have a grub menu that comes up, and I can load windows (though there appears to be two entries to windows which I can live with for now), however I cannot load Ubuntu unless the usb is in.  If the usb is in it appears that I am loading the version of Ubuntu on my HD, but I'm not 100% sure.  Any way to remedy this?

I'd like to be able to run Ubuntu on the computer without the USB.

Thank you

Comment: Try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash/197837#197837

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem

Grub, Ubuntu's bootloader, was installed on the flash drive, and not on your internal hard drive, as it should have been.

### Solution

Boot with the flash drive plugged in. Remove it once Ubuntu is booted up.

Run the following commands from a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Click on the "Recommended repair" button, and reboot.

#### Explanation

Boot-Repair installed Grub to your internal hard drive. This allows your computer to boot without depending on the bootloader that was installed on the flash drive.

---

#### Glossary

> **[Bootloader](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm)**: a piece of code that runs before any operating system is running. A bootloader is used to boot other operating
>   systems. Each operating system usually has its own bootloader.
>
> **[GRUB (*Grand Unified Bootloader*)](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/GRUB-GRand-Unified-Bootloader)**: a bootloader package developed to support multiple operating systems and allow the user to select among them during boot-up. It is Ubuntu's default bootloader.
>
> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly now.

Comment: Great! Please consider [accepting the answer or upvoting it](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask), in order to prevent it from showing up in the *Unanswered* section of the site. Thank you!