# how to install Ubuntu server In dual Boot PC with Ubuntu and XP?

Tags: server

I have a Dell Dimension 4600 desktop that I no longer use and I decided to turn it into a server. It is running Windows XP. Now, I had a flash drive that has Ubuntu 11.0 on it where I used it to install Ubuntu on another computer. Anyway, I downloaded Ubuntu Server onto the flash drive and used the flash drive to install Ubuntu on the desktop----When I realized that it was not Ubuntu Server but Ubuntu 11.0 I could not stop the install in fear of doing damage. So, now I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04(I did the upgrade) on this desktop. I want to install Ubuntu Server. How do I go about doing that?I am new to computers and Ubuntu . so please give me detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you want to keep the desktop version of Ubuntu 12.04 desktop or remove it and install Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Comment: I want to install the ubuntu server so it does not matter. This desktop is going to be used only for a server for my websites. I would like to keep the Windows XP though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need your desktop Ubuntu, you can install your server on the partition you used to install the desktop version. Its easy to recognize which partitions are currently occupied by the desktop version. The ones which show an "ext" partition while allocating partitions are the ones belonging to Ubuntu(desktop). So, first delete these partitions("partitions"(plural) because you **may** have allocated different ones for `/` `/home` `swap`, `/boot` etc.). So delete all of them, by pressing on the `-` button on partition screen and then re-allocate the partitions according to your convenience.

If you feel that the process to install/partition a server version of Ubuntu is different from the one for installing a desktop, then no, its not. You need not worry, only thing you keep in mind is delete "ext" partitions and reallocate them. This way, you won't have to [handle grub-rescue too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)!

Comment: ok, I deleted the partition for ubuntu-then I restarted the computer and got a black screen: that says "error:no such device:5ccfeb90c43-4b12-8e82-e13fa6108f57. grub rescue>             so, now what do I do?

Comment: Did you delete the partition from windows?

Comment: No, I deleted the one partition that only had 73.34 g of space(the space I gave to ubuntu), but I did not know that by doing that I would lose Grub also which left my pc with a black screen---- so I went back and re-installed ubuntu 11.0---would it not just be easier for me to install "LAMP"--Linux, apache2, mysql, php?   I have the computer back to the way it was before I deleted anything. I do not own a Windows boot disc so when I lose grub I lose the ability to boot into windows--thus the black screen with the error I posted earlier.