# Grub issue after update from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

Hi I have updated my dell T7500 desktop to Ubuntu 12.04 and when I tried to reboot I got grub rescue mode.

I have booted to live cd and used boot repair as instructed here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

At first I tried default repair but it didn't solve the problem, here is the first paste:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6761969/

Then I tried many options like purge grub, install it on only one partition (I tried several options) and at the end I did a default settings repair again and after this last one only windows boots automatically and I don't even get a choice of OS.

Here is my last paste:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6762811/

I don't know what else to do, I don't want to reinstall, how could I fix this?
thnks

EDIT:
I had also tried following these instructions on grub rescue 
[Recovering moved .mod files using grubrescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)
but unfortunately it says something about linux not found

Comment: Could you try removing boot flag from 1st drive of windows using gparted (live CD)? So it will boot from next drive (linux partition)

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but will try, I hope it will not mess up my ubuntu partitions

Comment: In gparted after selecting windows harddrive  > right click on that NTFS partition which have boot flag > label  > un-check boot

Comment: Thanks Sneetsher I have found it was select line to modify then menu option devices / manage flags and then I unticked boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gparted of live CD, remove 'boot flag' from first drive (Windows partition). So the machine will boot from next drive (Ubuntu partition which already is boot-able).