# How to fix/install GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm facing a problem of not being able to boot into Linux. I get the "grub-rescue" crash (as the one mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash). But my problem is really very different. I don't have to `/boot` directory on my hard-drive! I don't know how that happened.

My laptop was being slow. I had a VM running (using VMWare Workstation) and lot of browser tabs opened. The VM displayed a message that it wasn't getting enough memory and that it had to suspend the VM. So I clicked "ok" and waited for a minute or two. I have a 256Gb SSD and I thought that it should have suspended the VM. So I try to use my computer but everything appears to be frozen. So I restart. And then I get the "grub rescue" prompt. :-(

So I booted into a live USB disk and I see only the following directories on my hard-drive : `dev`, `proc`, `run`, `sys`, `usr`. So the OS is not able to see other directories, I guess. I guess the data is still there because the total size of the above directories is 119Gb and I have a free space of 70.2 Gb. Moreover, Ubuntu (the live USB one) is displaying "some contents unreadable" when I see the properties of my hard-drive.

I want to know is there any way I can repair my GRUB, get my other directories and get to work Ubuntu as it was before *without* installing a clean, new copy of Ubuntu. Is there any way to repair GRUB and/or hard-drive?

**P.S.**: I have tried using `boot-repair` through the Live USB but it doesn't help. I have used the 'Recommended Repair' option without success. In "advanced options" of boot repair utility the "GRUB location", "GRUB options" and "MBR options" is disabled. The only thing I can do is "Restore MBR" (which doesn't help). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do a live boot of ubuntu, open files and mount all the drives and close it. then open terminal and type *sudo nautilus* and then you can see all the contents. tell me  whether you can see a /boot or not

Comment: It sounds like a damaged filesystem. Even if `/boot` were on a separate partition, you would still see an empty directory in `/`. Try running `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` (change the `sda1` to the correct `/` partition in your case).

Comment: @terdon - I cannot find any drives on my `/dev`

Comment: @aveemashfaq - I don't have any drives to mount :-(

Comment: The `fsck` should be run from a live CD, not your damaged session.

Comment: I did tried it from a live USB :-/