# Problem upon restarting Ubuntu: grub rescue

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I am new to Ubuntu. I was restarting the system and got the following message:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/extcmd.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>'
```

What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear it sounds like your grub boot loader is corrupt.

You can do the following to repair it.

1. Boot from your installation CD choosing `try ubuntu without installing`.
2. Open a terminal.
3. enter the following commands:

**BUT FIRST** This assumes that your hard drive is showing as `/dev/sda` you may need to adjust. If you computer is under 10 years old and has only one hdd and your not running under a virtual machine then your hdd is probably lableled `/dev/sda`

These are the commands to reinstall the boot loader.

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to solve grub problems: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You don't even need to edit any configs.