# Grub rescue, what to do?

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

All I get is:

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode ...
Grub rescue>.
```

Please help I don't have any idea what to do.  I don't have the disk either.

Comment: Do you have another computer to work with or borrow? I'd suggest getting [Super grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) on a USB flash drive or CD then.

Comment: See this guide:http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-step-put-super-grub2-disk-into-an-usb-pendrive/

Comment: No I don't have access to another computer.  Can I just do something to factory reset the computer.

Comment: Unless you have some way to boot from an external media like USB or CD, no. If you have a few days, you could buy a cd from Canonical [here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146) and wait for it. What about an old Windows installation disk?

Comment: did you have windows on it before, sometimes there is a recovery partition you can reinstall windows from. Google you computer model recovery partition

Comment: It is possible to boot from the grub rescue prompt with no other software - that's why it's called grub *rescue*.  It's a bit painful, but some help is available [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/197833/39753), up until the part about copying missing files. Grub has two parts: one is in the boot sector (MBR, usually), which is what you have now.  The other is the grub code, which also includes the menu.  This normally is in /boot/grub on your working system.  You need to tell it where to look, and this is normally done by running `grub-install`

Answer (score 1):

enter these commands,

```
Grub rescue> set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
Grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
Grub rescue> insmod normal
Grub rescue> normal
```

this will allow you to login. Once you logged in run the commands in the terminal,

```
sudo grub-update
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and you should be done