# I have a dual boot of windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. i see a grub rescue error during start. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

I have a laptop with dual boot of windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10.

After installation everything was fine and working properly but after a shutdown and reboot I'm seeing the grub rescue error.

Please help me to fix this.
I installed Ubuntu by downloading the software from Canonical and using usb booting!

Comment: Posting the error message you are seeing would help. Did you install/deinstall or change something else before your reboot?

Comment: no i didn't..i dono how it happened also..after i installed and started using i didn't have any problem even when i reinstalled but it started after i shut down the laptop and started it the problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live CD image of [Ubuntu Secure Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix) and run the **Boot-Repair** tool. It should identify and correct any problems with your dual-boot setup, I think.

Comment: ok thanx will check this out!

Comment: you don't need `ubuntu secure remix`, you can add ppa and install `boot-repair` from live ubuntu cd/usb.

Comment: ok can u please explain me about adding ppa and installing boot repair??

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` and then
`sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get install boot-repair`.

That should do it.

Comment: thank you ver much! tat solved my issue! but i hav got 2 windows 7 loaders during boot now..1 from sda2 n 1 from sda3.
both takes me to windows 7 though..
why has tat happened?

Comment: In ubuntu run `sudo update-grub`. Assuming you only have one Windows 7 OS installed, it should only list one entry. If not, you may have to manually edit the GRUB configuration file.