# Fixing GRUB after fresh install from LiveCD on USB

Tags: grub2, mbr

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 using a LiveCD mounted on a USB drive.
When the USB drive isn't plugged in... things won't boot. I'm new to Ubuntu, so please bear with me.
After a bit of reading I see that GRUB needs to be fixed/ updated along with the MBR. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about this.
When booting with the USB stick plugged in, I get a menu that displays the different boot options and I can boot in to either Ubuntu or Windows 7 like I should be able to.
I also have the LiveCD USB stick listed as the first device accessed during the boot sequence. 
[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/142300/8973) thread seems to have a good walkthrough but I'm stuck on the first step.

When running `ls`, I see:
`(hd0), (hd0,msdos6), (hd0,msdos5), (hd0,msdos3), (hd0,msdos2)`, I think. This is from memory.

Starting the first step with `ls (hd0,msdos6)` returns `Bad filename` and 
`ls (hd0,msdos5)` etc returns `error: unknown filesystem`.

It would seem that msdos6 is the Ubuntu partition. But I can't access it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the main drive is /dev/sda, I would use

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

To (re)install it.

Comment: is there a way to verify that? that the main drive is /dev/sda I mean.

Comment: Type `sudo fdisk -l` to list all available drives (lines beggining with "Disk *****:"). In most common installations, there's only one :)

Comment: ok. better question... will doing this potentially mess everything up? :)

Comment: The `-l` option means "list". You'll just get some output :)

Comment: sounds good. thank you. i'll report back in after I try it out.

Comment: Great. "Unknown command 'sudo'"
Uh, any ideas?

Comment: Type `whoami` : are you root ?

Comment: I don't really mind reinstalling from the LiveCD... as I'll only really lose a couple of hours work... but I don't want to wipe the hard drive clean as it's a dual boot system. 
The real question is how to do this but have the MBR working right (unlike the first time).

Comment: During the installation process, choose the drive for GRUB installation correctly. If your hard drive is /dev/sda, then you should install GRUB on /dev/sda. If you have a UEFI system, read this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: That's the thing... I used the WUBI installer and installed it on the "existing Ubuntu partition"...ie, automatically.

Comment: off of a LinuxLive USB stick (added for clarification)