# Ubuntu partition problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I was trying to install a new operating system today, and I have tried before, but ever since the 14.04 release of Ubuntu, I have not been able to install any more OS. So, I tried formatting the Ubuntu OS partition into an unknown file type for it, so it would just go past the grub screen, and allow to me install this OS. However, once I did this and rebooted, this is what I found:

error: unknown filesystem.

Entering rescue mode...

grubrescue>

Now, before anyone says anything, I don't have a Windows repair disc, because my computer came with Windows on it. 2nd, I don't have a Ubuntu Live CD. I got Ubuntu approximately a year ago, and have since lost the location of the disc.

This is being written from my phone, thanks for reading. Hope somebody can help me. :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem.

Comment: Which operating system were you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Well fix is simple find the find bootable linux medium and install it on your computer. There is way to boot the computer via grub rescue but for that you need an Operating System but you just formatted it.
If you were doing a dual boot(ie Windows and Ubuntu) here's what you can do. Boot you computer let it come till grub rescue. Now windows is usually on the first partition so type

`set root=(hd0,msdos1)`

`chainloader +1`

`boot`

if its on the secondary drive, then

`set root=(hd1,msdos1)`

`drivemap -s hd0 hd1`

`chainloader +1`

`boot`

now if you are able to boot windows, open run `WindowsKey + R`
type `msconfig` move to the boot tab.
select windows boot loader and press `Set as default`. 
it guess this should fix.