# Grub rescue Unknown filesystem error

Tags: grub2

I have an HCL ME laptop which has a built in windows 7 os.
3 days before I have installed windows 8 along with windows7.
Yesterday I have downloaded ubuntu 14.04 iso and installed it using portable usb which created a new harddisk drive, but today when I opened it, it shows 
`unknown file system grub rescue error`.

Comment: Boot with ubuntu live and Follow here:-  http://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem

Answer (score 1):

After installing Windows 8 windows Removes Other bootloader (Ubuntu's) 
You can Reinstall Grub by following Documentation from ubuntu:- [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: THANKS FOR THE RESPONSE. BUT I AM UNABLE TO MOVE TO BOOT MENU ALSO.THE MOMENT I LOGON TO THE SYSTEM IT SHOWS GRUB ERROR AND UNABLE TO MOVE TO BOOT MENU

Answer (score 0):

```
unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

This error is due to deletion of the Ubuntu drive where your Ubuntu OS was installed, so set the Windows boot loader by typing the following commands at the grub rescue prompt:

```
set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

The drive msdos 7/6/5/4 depends upon the system user.