# GRUB unknown filesystem error

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, xps

I just created a USB bootable for ubuntu (but also tried other distributions) but it did not succeed as GRUB displays this error:

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0)(hd1)
```

I have a XPS 13 (9360) and I don't know how to fix this problem. I tried some solutions proposed over the web, but it did not work for me.

PS: I switch the SATA mode from RAID to AHCI but I don't think it's related

Comment: Are you saying that you properly installed Ubuntu (which version?) from the LiveUSB onto your XPS 13 without any errors, and the grub message is  the result after removing the LiveUSB and rebooting the XPS 13? Which 'some solutions' did you try?

Comment: No, I have Windows and I want to create a dual boot. So I put ubuntu (version 17.04) on an USB flash drive for boot on it and install ubuntu but I can't since GRUB (from the USB flash drive) give me this error. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue#answer-166338) for example but it failed every time after `insmod normal`.

Comment: The method you used to create the LiveUSB is suspect. Properly-made USB Flash drives normally use syslinux, not grub.

Comment: I made it through UNetbootin or rufus and it works on my second PC...

Comment: If your LiveUSB works properly, then it seems not an Ubuntu problem. Check your hardware settings in UEFI/BIOS, and check that you have prepared your Windows partition properly.

Comment: I did it but don't see anything related to my problem :(

Comment: “I switch the SATA mode from RAID to AHCI but I don't think it's related” – It's actually quite likely related to that because it changes the drive geometry. AHCI mode is usually preferred so it may pay off to fix the issues caused by the change instead of a reversion of that setting. Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? You may also perform the suggested fix of Boot-Repair which may already fix the issue entirely. In any case, please report back with the result. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Live installer has two boot modes. UEFI and BIOS/CSM. The UEFI boot uses grub2 and the BIOS boot use syslinux. If Windows is UEFI, best to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. And how you boot installer is then how it installs. Another user: Dell XPS 13 9360 16.04 worked after nvme firmware & BIOS update, 16.10 did not, new rEFInd for NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

- use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
- choose "MBR partition schema for UEFI"
- write in DD image mode