# Problem setting prefix in Grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm having trouble with the grub rescue. I am following the tutorial [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue), but I have the following problem.

I have to run the command

```
set prefix=(X,Y)/path
```

making `(X,Y)/path` the path where the `.mod` files are located. I found that directory to be `(hd0,gpt7)/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi`. When I set that prefix and try to run the `insmod` commands, I get:

```
error: file '/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/i386-pc/linux.mod' not found
```

What I think the problem is here, I have located the `linux.mod` file in the directory `/x86_64-efi`, but then GRUB tries to find it at `/x86_64-efi/i386-pc`, adding that directory that doesn't even exist there (I checked its existence with `ls`).

I made another test after this. I did:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/usr/lib/grub
```

But I got the same error:

```
error: file '/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod' not found
```

It seems as it always adds the path `i386-pc`.

How can I force GRUB to look for the files in the directory I want? Or is my problem something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wants grub's mod files which are normally at /boot/grub/x86_64-efi. as far as appending i386, sound like you are booting in Legacy mode not UEFI mode.

Comment: If i don't disable UEFI boot, I get directly to windows 10 (I have dual boot), I need to disable it to get to dual boot. What is legacy mode? How can I avoid that appending of i386?

Comment: you do not need to disable UEFI in order to dual boot. you have to reinstall ubuntu in 64bit UEFI mode. by disabling UEFI. you now have windows uefi mode and ubuntu in legacy mode which is what is causing the problem. this is not a dual boot, this a two single boots in different modes.  PS grub can't find it's files because Legacy boot can not read a gpt disk (a disk formated for UEFI)

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu in EFI mode should work, but is overkill; installing an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux should be sufficient. (OTOH, re-installing Ubuntu may be as easy if it's not yet been used or customized to any significant extent.) GRUB *can* read GPT disks in a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode install, but only if the appropriate GPT module (GRUB driver) is loaded. GRUB should be set up with this module configured if a GPT disk was detected when it was installed, but it might not be if a GPT disk was not detected. Unless I'm misreading, the "unknown filesystem" is a message from another question.