# "grub rescue unknown filesystem/device" error is only passed through by pressing multiple ESC in HP

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 like this, with the 64.77 GB partition being used for Ubuntu :

[image]

Whenever I restart/start my PC (Elitebook 8560w Workstation HP) the grub selection menu does not come directly, I have to:

- Keep pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, until the boot menu comes up,
- Press <kbd>F9</kbd>, I can select the hard-disk that I want to boot from (SSD or hard disk).
- Only now does the normal grub menu shows up.

Otherwise, I will encounter the "unknown file system" error and nothing happens.

I have tried the following solutions already to no avail:

- [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue) including writing commands to rescue terminal
- Boot Repair application in Ubuntu.

However, none of them could work!. Moreover, writing `ls` to grub rescue shows only (hd0) and `ls (hd0)` shows again unknown filesystem error. So I am not able to move forward with this terminal solution.

Is there any possible case/solution for my situation?

Comment: So you have two disks?

Comment: @Yufenyuy Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152127/revisions) as I had to edit yours to make it clearer...

Comment: @Fabby, it's Ok. I actually thought it was okay to leave `Cloudinit` unchanged. So instead of editing it to `Cloud-init `... I left it unchanged.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider Please scroll down and compare your edit with mine: it's not just about grammar and spelling but overall logic and readability (e.g. showing the picture). Please also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your your own edits in the future as from this point forward I'll just decline them if they're no good.... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby, Okay thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 10 Anniversary Update**, and the more recent **Windows 10 Creators Update**, have a really bad habit of wiping out Linux partitions on **MBR disks**. Microsoft has known about this bug for quite some time, but has chosen not to fix it. Sounds like you're a victim.

Recovery is possible, but it can be tricky.

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `Software & Updates` and make sure that all of your software repositories (except proposed) are enabled.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update           # update the software database
sudo apt-get install testdisk # install testdisk
man testdisk                  # read the manual
sudo testdisk                 # start testdisk
```

You can also get specific instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Help for photorec here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

**Note**: after recovery, strongly consider changing your MBR formatted disk to GPT format, so future MS updates won't wipe it again.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by

- Activating UEFI boot ( it was working with Legacy since UEFI is not recommended for my HP)
- Changing boot priority order in UEFI to OS Boot Manager at top

I did not have enough time to try the other solutions, but I appreciate them as well.