# Ubuntu single boot unknown filesystem error (Not Duplicate)

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have a Samsung 860 EVO 500 GB SSD that is just running a single boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop. First off I have tried [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem) and I can't get past the `ls` portion of the solution. Which was similar to [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue), When I input the following:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

I am still unable to boot into Ubuntu. Also both of this issues have a dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows) mine is a single boot. All that to clarify this is not a duplicate question.

When booting I get the following error:

> error: unknown filesystem.

I tried to find the filesystem with the following but did not find it.

[image: ls filesystem is unknown]

***UPDATE 10/23/2022***

Taking the advice from @carles-mateo I installed ubuntu on a separate hard drive. I connected the Samsung 860 EVO 500 GB SSD to the new system on bootup I get the following when the hard drive is connected:

[image]

The new system starts up and I can view the disk from the Disks app. Here are all the partitions:

First:

[image: First]

Second:

[image: Second]

Fifth:

[image: Fifth]

Free Space:

[image: Free Space]

It seems that the First partition can be mounted and opened:

[image: mount 1]

It take a moment to load but here is what I see:

[image: mount 2]

Comment: Could you clarify a few things? (1) has the machine been running Ubuntu 20.04 successfully for a period of time before this error appeared? (2) have you grabbed an installation USB to boot into a Live Session to run some tests on the SSD to see if it's toast? 

Comment: @matigo It has been running for a 2+ years now. I have tried to use the live boot to inspect the drive but couldn't find anything. Can you elaborate on which tests you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Long history short:

- Grab a new drive
- Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it
- Connect your old drive using an external case, connected by USB
- Make a backup with dd from the drive connected to USB, to a file (so you can recover if something is destroyed)

My expectation is that, connected as USB using an external case, to a full Linux with all the drivers installed (msdos/windows), it will be able to recognize the drive.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! that helped! please see my updates. Also how do I make a backup with dd?